# Array are adding only in 0th index

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am writing a function in which i need to add the elements into an array.I am getting the data from my database.When add the element into it all the elements are only being added to the Array[0] of the rowData.

```
private createRowData() {
        var rowData:any[] = [];
        this.wakanda.catalog.then(ds => {
            ds.Group.query({select : 'groupName'}).then(op => {
                for(let entity of op['entities']){
                    rowData.push(
                    {row : entity.groupName});
                }
            });
        });
        return rowData;
    }
```

My output is like this

[image]

I need something like this

[image]

How do i solve it

Thanks in advance

Comment: This line looks suspect to me: `var rowData:any[] = [];`. Try removing the `var`.

Comment: Everything is good, you are just logging your data before the end of the promise. So chrome show you an empty array, but since you expend it the promise is done so chrome fill it.

Comment: i tried removing the var but still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the above function you are using DB call which is async and then you are sending the response without waiting for the result.

So, In this case, you will get the rowData.length 0.

send the result after the callback response.

try this:

```
    private createRowData() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var rowData: any[] = [];
            this.wakanda.catalog.then(ds => {
                ds.Group.query({ select: 'groupName' }).then(op => {
                    for (let entity of op['entities']) {
                        rowData.push({ row: entity.groupName });
                    }
                    resolve(rowData); // Send result from here
                });
            }).catch(reject);
        })
    }
```

Comment: it return the value as i expect but the how to terminate the promise since the code freezes after the return

Comment: it generate error when i change my code to your new updated, I figured out the problem is with the asyc call that is happening in the code it return the value before it actually have the data

Comment: i fixed it by making a function call after return statement